# R.java file cannot be resolved in application in android studio. Give me suggestions that what are the things I should check for this issue.

Tags: android

R.java file cannot be resolved in application in android studio. Give me suggestions that what are the things I should check for this issue. Thank you for advance.

Comment: Please search on google there are so many answers for this.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for R.java error.

You may also try this in Android Studio. Go to Tools --> Android --> click on 'Sync project files with gradle'.